# Histogram ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot my percentiles with a histogram using ggplot2. I have the following code for my histogram

```
qplot(kvaobs, geom="histogram", xlim = c(0, 1), binwidth = 0.1, main = "",
      xlab = "Percentil", ylab = "Frekvens", fill=I("darkred"), col=I("black"))
```

I receive the following error:

```
Warning message:
Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).
```

It means that one observation is excluded. In the histogram I receive I only have 12 observations. But if I use the built-in function for histogram in rstudio

```
hist(kvaobs)
```

All of the observations are included in the histogram. Anyone knows what I have defined wrong in my function for the histogram using ggplot?

I have the following observations

```
dput(kvaobs)
c(0.52475, 0.5575, 0.44175, 0.5735, 0.63725, 0.79225, 0.29275, 
0.94675, 0.988, 0.11625, 0.67, 0.507, 0.0495)
```

Comment: Please edit the output of ``dput(kvabos)`` into your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when you have data outside the axis ranges in the plot.

1. Check your data for min and max and compare to axis range
2. Try to tweak the axis limits in you code.
3. Try another binwidth.

Comment: All of my observations are inside the x limit (0 to 1). I have the following observations: 0.52475, 0.55750, 0.44175, 0.57350, 0.63725, 0.79225, 0.29275, 0.94675, 0.98800, 0.11625, 0.67000, 0.50700, and 0.04950. So I do not understand how I could have data outside the axis ranges.